# Tracking down the admin contact of an expired GeoTrust certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

One of our client's sites has an invalid certificate and we don't know who provided the certificate. All of our contacts with the client have since left the company.

Is there something like a WHOIS database for certificates that will show me who the administrator is?

We host the site, so we're responsible for generating the CSR (certificate signing request).

Also, when a certificate is about to expire, does the cert authority send out expiration notices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the second half of your question: Yes, typically the the issuer will send you notices when the certificate is about to expire, if for no other reason than they want your business again.

Which brings me back to the first part of your question:  It really doesn't matter who issued the original certificate, other than price break there is no real advantage to renewing a cert rather than replacing (in reality you're always replacing it).  So I would suggest picking a CA that you are comfortable with, and start using that new CA for all your certificates (either replacing them all right away, or as they expire).

This way, you now know where everything comes from and you can establish an account that you can use to keep track of everything.

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't even bother trying to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact GeoTrust Support online - http://www.geotrust.com/about/contact/support-form/

**OR** you can reach out to them on Twitter - http://www.twitter.com/GeoTrustSupport